# How to use DATEADD in a case statement in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table with a column PERIOD_DAYS that is in varchar but contains a lot of numbers. I have another column called FIRST_DATETIME, which is in datetime data type. I want to add the numbers in the PERIOD_DAYS to the FIRST_DATETIME to get the FINAL datetime. So if datetime = '2020-01-01' + 2 DAYS, the final_datetime should be = '2020-01-03'

I have a query that contains a case statement, that says if the first_datetime IS NULL, then default the final_datetime to 0. However, I keep getting an error.

This works:

```
select
ID,
PERIOD_DAYS,
FIRST_DATETIME,
DATEADD('days',try_to_number(PERIOD_DAYS), FIRST_DATETIME) as FINAL_DATETIME
from TBL_A a
group by ID,PERIOD_DAYS,FINAL_DATETIME
```

Does not work:

```
select
ID,
PERIOD_DAYS,
FIRST_DATETIME,
case when try_to_number(PERIOD_DAYS) IS NULL then 0 else DATEADD('days',try_to_number(PERIOD_DAYS), FIRST_DATETIME) END as FINAL_DATETIME
from TBL_A a
group by ID,PERIOD_DAYS,FINAL_DATETIME
```

I need the second query to work to take into account the non-numeric values in period_days columns.

Comment: don't screenshot error messages. post them as text

Comment: Can you try using the zeroifnull Snowflake function and see if you still get  the error. zeroifnull ( DATEADD('days',try_to_number(PERIOD_DAYS))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as you have it is because you CASE is returning `0` which is a NUMBER on one branch and TIMESTAMP_NTZ on the other.

These are not compatible types. I would recommend using NULL instead of zero.

thus:

```
CASE WHEN try_to_number(PERIOD_DAYS) IS NULL THEN null 
     ELSE DATEADD('days',try_to_number(PERIOD_DAYS), FIRST_DATETIME) 
END as FINAL_DATETIME
```

Given this only has 2 branches a IFF can be used instead:

```
IFF(try_to_number(PERIOD_DAYS) IS NULL, null, DATEADD('days',try_to_number(PERIOD_DAYS), FIRST_DATETIME) ) as FINAL_DATETIME
```

Comment: this helped a lot, thank you for your help!